# How to direct to different pages in jsp according to the button pressed?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to use 2 buttons(in jsp) one for submitting(after validating using javascript) and the other to save as draft(it should send data to a jsp page).I want to know how to use

```
document.forms[0].actionValue.value = '1';
document.forms[0].submit();
```

this or any other way of redirecting page according to the button clicked.

P.s:-I am new to JSP and JavaScript.

Thanks in Adv!!!!

Comment: Save as draft button will save the data on client side i.e. html5 feature or it will save on server?

Comment: @RaviKumar yes you are correct but presently I want only how to divert the page according to the button pressed!!!any suggestions?

Comment: Then you can proceed with the answer given by @Madhu.

Comment: If you don't want to redirect with javascript then you can follow another make both the button as submit as follow 
<button name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
   <button name="submit" value="save" type="submit">Save</button>
point action url to a servlet and on servlet check the value for request.getParameter("submit") if it is submit then dispatch it to the submit.jsp or if it is save then dispatch it to save.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved easily by using Javascript.

You have to submit the form to different jsp file.

```
<form name='f1' action=''>
.....
 <input type='button' name='b1' value='Submit' onclick='return chkAndSubmit(this)'/>
 <input type='button' name='b2' value='Save as Draft' onclick='return chkAndSubmit(this)'/>
......

</form>
```

In the script please use as follow.

```
 function chkAndSubmit(ele) {
  if(ele.getAttribute('name') == 'b1') {
     // Do validation here
    document.f1.setAttribute("action","submit.jsp")
    document.f1.submit();
  } else{
   document.f1.setAttribute("action","save.jsp")
    document.f1.submit();      
  }
 }
```

Now Based on the button pressed the form will be submitted to the different jsp page. Here you can do ur process to save as draft or something...

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: @ Madhu :-Thanks. Its going into the function but not into the if(or) else condition . any other suggestions?

Comment: its working for the first button (submit)..but not for save...sorry for your trouble!

Comment: @Vishnu Hi buddy could you please post ur code? It will help to provide better answer.